# Android EditText in a ListView - Erratic / Unexpected results

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I've been working on a client/server application for a few months now for my final year project of my undergraduates degree, I'm currently working on a ListView which should show a list of products and allow the user to enter a value representing the quantity of that item in stock. I've managed to get the View and Adapter looking right but the EditText is causing me issues, I've spent hours googling for answers and scoured StackOverflow for similar problems but what I've found either hasn't applied or hasn't solved the issue.

I'm almost certain its a recycler issue but the root of the problem seems to allude me, the values entered into the EditText seems to be inserted into several positions in my hashmap, not just one, and scrolling through the list quickly causes most-of if not all of the views to show the same value! Here is my Adapter class in full and I'm happy to provide any other code that helps, thank you in advance.

```
public class StockAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Stock> {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Stock data[] = null;
Map<Integer, String> stockHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 

public StockAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Stock[] data)
{
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    StockHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

        // Instantiate StockHolder object.
        holder = new StockHolder();
        // Get views
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stockName);
        holder.etValue = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etValue);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (StockHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Get stock object from data set.
    Stock stock = data[position]; 

    holder.txtName.setText(stock.Name);

    // Put stock id in a variable - used for referencing the right stock item.
    final int id = stock.Id;
    String oldText = stockHashMap.get(id);
    // Check if the value of oldText is null.
    holder.etValue.setText(oldText == null ? "" : oldText);

    // Create addTextChangedListener for this EditText
    holder.etValue.addTextChangedListener(
            new TextWatcher(){
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    stockHashMap.put(id, editable.toString());
                }
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
    return convertView;
}
static class StockHolder
{
    int id;
    TextView txtName;
    EditText etValue;
}
}
```

RE: Matt C's Answer: Added the following but no better.

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    if (data == null) return 0;
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Stock getItem(int position)
{
    return data[position];
}
```

Comment: it seems to be correct, try to print out the values stored in the stockHashMap to double check if it's dirty or not.

Comment: I added a two verbose log statements (one just after the `stockHashMap.get(id)` and another just after `stockHashMap.put(id, editable.toString());` to print out what was being set and pulled in the HashMap and it all looked fine; what I did notice was that the latter would often set the input entered into one EditText into two or three ids in the HashMap! :S

Answer (score 0):

I personally have found that if I do not override the [getCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount%28%29) function in an adapter I get all sorts of weird unexplained issues. In your case I think I would do a null check and then return the size of the Stock[] array named "data". I can't guarantee this will fix your issue but it's always "cured" random weirdness in these cases for me. You may also want to override [getItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29) for completeness' sake.

Comment: No avail I'm afraid, here is what I added to the adapter:

[SNIP: Moved code to the bottom of my Question for readability.]

Answer (score 0):

As you have a custom getView() try extending BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter, it's much simpler for your case. ArrayAdapter are suits best for simple things like each row is a TextView...

Comment: Not sure how I would go about this, and how it would benefit me, does it do the heavy lifting for me? Any advice / extra comments?